# How could i pass the field and the int value to the set method in Date class?

Tags: java, oop

I want to pass the field and the int value to the set method in the class Date.But i dont know how to pass the value to the method and do the changes there after.

```
class Date{
    private int year=1970;
    private int month=1;
    private int day=1;


    public void set(){
        //I wanna pass the field and the date from the set method in Demo class
    }

}

class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Date d1=new Date();
        d1.set(Date.YEAR,2016);
        d1.set(Date.MONTH,05);
        d1.set(Date.DAY,30);


    }

}
```

Comment: *I want to pass the field and the int value to the set method in the class* - why?

Comment: Why are you rolling your own date type?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm learning java. So this is just to practise those methods and concepts. Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're learning Java (otherwise, consider using existing java support for Dates) you can do:

```
class Date{
    private int year=1970;
    private int month=1;
    private int day=1;


    public void setYear(int year){
        this.year = year;
    }
    public void setMonth(int month) {
       this.month = month;
    }
    public void setDay(int day) {
       this.day = day;
    }
}
```

Another way is to instantiate the value directly in constructor:

```
class Date {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    public Date(int year, int month, int day) {
       this.year = year;
       this.month = month;
       this.day   = day;
    }
}
```